# Como imprimir lista de objetos JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html-meta-tag

Estou implementando os posts do facebook de uma determinada página do meu site e estou com dificuldades de entender como imprimir a seguinte estrutura de JSON:

```
{
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "created_time": "2017-11-16T19:52:28+0000",
        "message": "Teste | JAGUAFRANGOS | A Agência produziu os layouts, vídeo institucional e toda a cobertura do desfile em comemoração ao aniversário de 70 anos de Jaguapitã e aos 25 anos da JAGUAFRANGOS na cidade. ",
        "story": "Teste",
        "id": "157428127680859_1519494691474189"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5UXhOVGMwTWpneE1qYzJPREE0TlRrNkxUWTJPREU1T1Rrek1UazROemMxTXprek1USVBER0ZA3YVY5emRHOXllVjlwWkE4ZA01UVTNOREk0TVRJM05qZA3dPRFU1WHpFMU1UazBPVFEyT1RFME56UXhPRGtQQkhScGJXVUdXZAzNzZAkFFPQZDZD",
        "after": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5UXhOVGMwTWpneE1qYzJPREE0TlRrNkxUYzVOemM0TWpZAMU9EYzJNVGsyTXpjMk16RVBER0ZA3YVY5emRHOXllVjlwWkE4ZA01UVTNOREk0TVRJM05qZA3dPRFU1WHpFMU1UQXdNemM1TURVM05UTXlNREVQQkhScGJXVUdXZA0lOOWdFPQZDZD"
      },
      "next": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5UXhOVGMwTWpneE1qYzJPREE0TlRrNkxUYzVOemM0TWpZAMU9EYzJNVGsyTXpjMk16RVBER0ZA3YVY5emRHOXllVjlwWkE4ZA01UVTNOREk0TVRJM05qZA3dPRFU1WHpFMU1UQXdNemM1TURVM05UTXlNREVQQkhScGJXVUdXZA0lOOWdFPQZDZD"
    }
  },
  "id": "123456789101112113"
}
```

Tentei esse código mas não consegui imprimir na tela a lista de objetos:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON( "posts.txt", function(data) {
        console.log('loaded');
        var data = []; // create array here
        $.each(data.posts, function (index, posts) {
            data.push(posts.data); //push values here
        });
        console.log(data); // see the output here
    });
});
```

Comment: O que aparece na tela?

Comment: Nada na verdade. Era para aparecer no console mas mesmo assim não consegui obter a lista desejada. Me retorna apenas "[ ]"

Comment: Tem algum erro no console? E você tem duas variaveis com o mesmo nome `data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para imprimir a lista você pode usar a seguinte função:

```js
var obj = {
    "posts": {
        "data": [
            {
                "created_time": "2017-11-16T19:52:28+0000",
                "message": "Teste | JAGUAFRANGOS | A Agência produziu os layouts, vídeo institucional e toda a cobertura do desfile em comemoração ao aniversário de 70 anos de Jaguapitã e aos 25 anos da JAGUAFRANGOS na cidade. ",
                "story": "Teste",
                "id": "157428127680859_1519494691474189"
            }
        ],
        "paging": {
            "cursors": {
                "before": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5UXhOVGMwTWpneE1qYzJPREE0TlRrNkxUWTJPREU1T1Rrek1UazROemMxTXprek1USVBER0ZA3YVY5emRHOXllVjlwWkE4ZA01UVTNOREk0TVRJM05qZA3dPRFU1WHpFMU1UazBPVFEyT1RFME56UXhPRGtQQkhScGJXVUdXZAzNzZAkFFPQZDZD",
                "after": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5UXhOVGMwTWpneE1qYzJPREE0TlRrNkxUYzVOemM0TWpZAMU9EYzJNVGsyTXpjMk16RVBER0ZA3YVY5emRHOXllVjlwWkE4ZA01UVTNOREk0TVRJM05qZA3dPRFU1WHpFMU1UQXdNemM1TURVM05UTXlNREVQQkhScGJXVUdXZA0lOOWdFPQZDZD"
            },
            "next": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5UXhOVGMwTWpneE1qYzJPREE0TlRrNkxUYzVOemM0TWpZAMU9EYzJNVGsyTXpjMk16RVBER0ZA3YVY5emRHOXllVjlwWkE4ZA01UVTNOREk0TVRJM05qZA3dPRFU1WHpFMU1UQXdNemM1TURVM05UTXlNREVQQkhScGJXVUdXZA0lOOWdFPQZDZD"
        }
    },
    "id": "123456789101112113"
};

function ImprimirObjeto(obj, retornarSaida)
{
    var saida = '';

    if($.isArray(obj) || typeof(obj) == 'object')
    {
        for(var i in obj)
            saida += i + ' => ' + ImprimirObjeto(obj[i], true) + '\n';
    }
    else
        saida += obj;

    if(retornarSaida && retornarSaida == true)
        return saida;
    else
     console.log(saida);
}

ImprimirObjeto(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Créditos a [Rayiez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17512537).

Caso deseja imprimir apenas uma propriedade você pode usar o [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Ex:

```
console.log(obj.posts.data.map(m => m.story));
```

Agora, se a ideia é só ler o objeto no console você pode usar o [stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) Ex:

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Uau! Obrigado. Na verdade a intenção é imprimir a lista direto no meu HTML mesmo. Usei o console apenas como exemplo para teste.